# PySpark - Combine DF columns into named StructType

Tags: python, database, dataframe, pyspark

I'm looking to combine multiple columns of a PySpark Data Frame into one column of the `StructType`.

Let's say I have a data frame like so:

```
columns = ['id', 'dogs', 'cats']
vals = [(1, 2, 0),(2, 0, 1)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(vals, columns)
```

I'd like the resulting data frame to resemble this (not as it would actually be printed but to give an idea of what I mean if you aren't already familiar with StructType):

```
id | animals
1  | dogs=2, cats=0
2  | dogs=0, cats=1
```

Right now I am able to accomplish what I want with putting this:

```
StructType(
    [StructField('dogs', IntegerType(), True),
    [StructField('cats', IntegerType(), True)
)
```

at the end of my `udf`s, however, I'd rather just do it with a single function. I'd be surprised if one doesn't exist.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**If you need a `map` column**: create literal columns with the column names as keys and then use [`create_map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.create_map) function to construct the map column you needed:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import create_map, lit
new_df = df.select(
    'id', 
     create_map(lit('dogs'), 'dogs', lit('cats'), 'cats').alias('animals')
     #                key  :  val,        key   :   val
)

new_df.show(2, False)
#+---+----------------------+
#|id |animals               |
#+---+----------------------+
#|1  |[dogs -> 2, cats -> 0]|
#|2  |[dogs -> 0, cats -> 1]|
#+---+----------------------+

new_df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- id: long (nullable = true)
# |-- animals: map (nullable = false)
# |    |-- key: string
# |    |-- value: long (valueContainsNull = true)
```

**If you need a `struct` column**: Use the [`struct`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.struct) function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct
new_df = df.select('id', struct('dogs', 'cats').alias('animals'))
new_df.show(2, False)
#+---+-------+
#|id |animals|
#+---+-------+
#|1  |[2, 0] |
#|2  |[0, 1] |
#+---+-------+

new_df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- id: long (nullable = true)
# |-- animals: struct (nullable = false)
# |    |-- dogs: long (nullable = true)
# |    |-- cats: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Perfect! Appreciate the explanation for both maps and structs.