# Scala exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Scala programming and am using IntelliJ IDE. I am getting the below exception when I run my Scala sample code. Not sure if I am missing any dependency.

Sample code

```
package com.assessments.example

object Example extends App {


  //Create a spark context, using a local master so Spark runs on the local machine
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("ScoringModel").getOrCreate()

  //importing spark implicits allows functions such as dataframe.as[T]
  import spark.implicits._

  //Set logger level to Warn
  Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.WARN)

  case class CustomerData(
                           customerId: String,
                           forename: String,
                           surname: String
                         )
  case class FullName(
                       firstName: String,
                       surname: String
                     )

  case class CustomerModel(
                            customerId: String,
                            forename: String,
                            surname: String,
                            fullname: FullName
                          )

  val customerData = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("src/main/resources/customer_data.csv").as[CustomerData]

  val customerModel = customerData
    .map(
      customer =>
        CustomerModel(
          customerId = customer.customerId,
          forename = customer.forename,
          surname = customer.surname,
          fullname = FullName(
            firstName = customer.forename,
            surname = customer.surname))
    )

  customerModel.show(truncate = false)

  customerModel.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("src/main/resources/customerModel.parquet")
}
```

Exception message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer$.empty()Lscala/collection/GenTraversable;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSessionExtensions.<init>(SparkSessionExtensions.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.<init>(SparkSession.scala:793)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.builder(SparkSession.scala:984)
    at com.assessments.example.Example$.delayedEndpoint$com$assessments$example$Example$1(Example.scala:10)
    at com.assessments.example.Example$delayedInit$body.apply(Example.scala:6)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:563)
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:561)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:926)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
    at com.assessments.example.Example$.main(Example.scala:6)
    at com.assessments.example.Example.main(Example.scala)
```

I am using spark version 3.1.2 and Scala version of 2.12.10. When I checked this version of Scala seems to support spark.

Appreciate any guidance on how to get this resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem I would not use case-class as schema. Also I would go with spark dataframes. You define your schema as follows:

```
val dataSchema = StructType(Array(
            StructField("customerId", StringType, true),
            StructField("forename", StringType, true),
            StructField("surname", StringType, true)
        ))
// Load data
val rawDf = context.read.format("csv")
            .option("delimiter", ",") //edit accordingly
            .option("escape", "\"")  //edit accordingly
            .option("header", "true") 
            .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
            .schema(dataSchema)
            .load("src/main/resources") // Will read all the csv in directory

rawDf.show()
```

Once you can see your data then move on to transformations. Create a Struct or a Map data type as suggested here

[PySpark - Combine DF columns into named StructType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846050/pyspark-combine-df-columns-into-named-structtype)

This is in pySpark but the idea is the same. You play with sparkSQL.

Once you do this simply write to parquet.

```
finalDf.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("src/main/resources/customerModel")
```

Notice the output path, there is no file name there. Spark will writeout the data in customerModel directory.